# Oracle subquery with JSON_VALUE limited to 1024 characters

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle18c

I have a problem with Oracle JSON_VALUE in subquery/CTE.
For testing I have this query:

```
WITH test_CTE AS (
    SELECT
        LENGTH(val) AS len,
        JSON_VALUE(val, '$.a2' RETURNING VARCHAR2) AS res
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TO_CLOB('{
        a:100,
        x: {
            obj: {
                valS: "String dummy value"
            },
            valI: 1000000000
        },
        y: [
            {
                t: "test string property"
            },
            {
                t: "test2 string property"
            }
        ],
        z: [
            {
                str: "My Test String with special characters $#@!"
            }
        ],
        a2:200,
        b:100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, 
        c:100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
        d:100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
        e:10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
        f:10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        }') AS val
        FROM DUAL
    )
) 
SELECT
    test_CTE.LEN,
    test_CTE.RES
FROM
    test_CTE;
```

And the result of this query is:
`1025 | NULL`

If I run just the part of the CTE the result will be correct
`1025 | 200`

If the length of the JSON object will be <=1024 it works even with the CTE/subquery.
Did anyone notice the same limitation?
Why it works in a query but not in subquery/CTE?
Is this some kind of setting on Oracle? I didn't find any limitation in the documentation that will be related to this scenario.

Database version:
`Oracle 18c, Full version: 18.12.0.0.0`

Comment: Your code works fine in this db fiddle, in version `Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=860ad7a91c5919bd2a302319dd86100a

Comment: And length of your input is 1052, not 1025. Will you get the same difference if you insert this value in table and then select it with CTE?

Comment: It works fine on 18.3.0.0.0 as well.
These are the only 2 versions that I have - 18.12.0.0.0 and 18.3.0.0.0

Comment: I'm selecting the length of the VAL that should represent the length when it is processed by the database.
But the same problem is also with values in the table.

Comment: Also works on 19.0. If you do `JSON_VALUE(val, '$.a2' RETURNING VARCHAR2 ERROR ON ERROR)` does it return anything interesting? Or still null.

Comment: It is still null. IMHO it looks like a bug in 18.12.0.0 version